# Google Spreadsheets: Find last unique value in column given some conditions

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I have an excel like the attached below.

[image]

I want to find the last unique value (transaction) of column **A**, given that column **I** is > 0.

Any tip how to achieve this?

Comment: Is this for Google Spreadsheets, or Microsoft Excel?

Comment: In Excel 365: `=XMATCH(UNIQUE(A2:A1000), IF(I2:I1000>0, A2:A1000, ""), 0, -1)`. You can probably do the same in G Sheets, but might have to enclose it all in `=ARRAYFORMULA(...)`. This will give you the row index of the required items. Use with INDEX(...) to get to revelant column entries.

Comment: Sorry, it is in google sheets. Will try this solution shortly

Comment: `=LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:$A$1000=$A$2),$I$2:$I$1000)` did the trick from https://trumpexcel.com/find-last-occurrence/